# EXC_BAD_access code=1 address 0x NSURLConnection JSON

Tags: ios, json, uitableview

Doing JSON work in my iPhone app, trying to list the json in a tableview, the json can be found here: appwhittle.com/api/db_all.php

I need this json to work with both android and ios, since i made the android app first it works without problem on the android device, but i cant seem to figure out what is wrong.

SearchViewController.m:

```
//
//  SearchViewController.m
//  Night Locations
//
//  Created by Stian Wiik Instebø on 12/9/13.
//  Copyright (c) 2013 Stian Wiik Instebø. All rights reserved.
//

#import "SearchViewController.h"
#import "SBJson4.h"

@interface SearchViewController ()

@end

@implementation SearchViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    self.title = @"Search for location";

    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://appwhittle.com/api/db_all.php"];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    data = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
}

- (void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)theData
{
    [data appendData:theData];
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;

    news = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
    [mainTableView reloadData];
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    UIAlertView *errorView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"The download could not complete" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [errorView show];
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
}

- (int)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (int)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [news count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MainCell"];
    if (cell == nil){
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"MainCell"];
    }
    [cell release];

    cell.textLabel.text = [[news objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"name"];

    return cell;
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

SearchViewController.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface SearchViewController : UIViewController {
    IBOutlet UITableView *mainTableView;

    NSArray *news;
    NSMutableData *data;
}

@end
```

The error appears at the line: `cell.textLabel.text = [[news objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"name"];` where i get the title into one of the rows in the tableView.

What seems to be the problem, is it the formatting on the json? if it is, is there any way to get around it?

Programming for iOS 7

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: What is the **error**?

Comment: Make sure your news NSArray contains objects responds to objectForKey like NSDictionary.

Comment: The error is EXC_BAD_ACCESS (Code=1, address=0x40000000c)

Comment: Can you log after loading NSLog(@"%@", news);

Comment: Log: 2013-12-09 13:20:01.621 Night Locations[1881:a0b] (null)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use these many lines use below code for it :

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request =[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://appwhittle.com/api/db_all.php"]];
NSData *returnData = [ NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse: nil error: nil ];
NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSError *err = nil;
NSMutableArray *search = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[returnString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&err];
NSLog(@"Search %@",search);
```

Comment: Getting this error; Non-ASCII characters are not allowed outside of literals and identifiers, on NSLog

Comment: Worked like a charm, i can see the output, now i only need to add it to the tableViewCell

Comment: Declare the search variable in .h file, and then use the below line of code. And print the log.

NSString *str = [[[search valueForKey:@"locations"]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"location"];

Comment: 2 sec, just grabbed something to eat :) ill try it now

Comment: Declared search variable in headerfile, then `NSString *str = [[[search valueForKey:@"locations"]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"location"];` and `NSLog(@"%@", str);` does not show in the tableview

Comment: Write the *str statement in cellforrowatindex method of tableview.
and then you can see the log in your debug area

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: I dont have a method called that

Comment: check out below answer

Comment: "Try to use NSMutableArray for collecting data from connectionDidFinishLoading method." this one?

Comment: last one, also you need to set the delegate and datasource of tableview from xib, and mention its delegate protocol in .h file.

Comment: i would probably leave for the day need to go back to home. See you later

Comment: ive done the two delegate and datasource, importet appdelegate.h into my h file

Comment: k then write the below three methods

Answer (score 1):

```
-(NSInteger) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [search count];
}


-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *store=@"cell";
    UITableViewCell *utvc = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:store];
    if(utvc == nil)
    {
        utvc = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:nil];
    }
  NSString *str = [[[search valueForKey:@"locations"]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"location"];
  NSLog(@"%@", str);
    return utvc;

}

-(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
}
```

Comment: You might have not set the delegate from xib, right click on the tableview in xib and the drag the delegate to file's owner. Also the datasource

Comment: im using storyboard tho? but have done that with both

Comment: mention the protocol of it on .h file <UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDatasource>

Comment: leaving for the day get my details and we could be in contact, paste "about.me/ravirajjadeja" in web address of your browser

Comment: mentioned <UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDatasource> still nothing

Comment: stian buzz me if you wish

Comment: seemed to got it working :) just had to change somethings like the json string received from the db, but it seems to crash whenever i scroll and click an item

Comment: dont know about it, i would suggest you to read raywenderlich examples he gives good kinda explanation

Comment: Why are you using jsonclass, straightly use NSMutableArray to store the data and then retrieve the data from NSMutableArray object. Don't make the code complex.

the json itself is a object and no need to create any new JSonclass object. use json in cellforrowatindex and didselectrowatindexpath method

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `NSMutableArray` for collecting data from `connectionDidFinishLoading` method.